# Is there a name for a point on the circumference of a circle?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there an eloquent name for a point located on the circumference of a circle?

Comment: His majesty of circumferenceville, The Point. I just couldn't stop imagining a single point with arms and legs dressed in court regalia.

Comment: Jimmy. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

A point on a circle is nothing more than a point on a *circle*:

It is an ordered pair $(x, y)$ that satisfies the equation of a circle $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 =  r^2 $ where $(h, k)$ is the center of the circle, and $r$ the radius of the circle. (The radius is the distance from the center of a circle to *any* point on the circle. This distance is constant for every point on a given circle.)

The *circumference* of a circle is a measure of *length* around the circle.

Comment: Nicely precise. OP was, perhaps thinking of a *disk*, in which case one would have to speak of a “boundary point”.

Answer (score 0):

You could score some extra eloquence by using an active verb:

> Point $A$ *lies on* the unit circle centered at the origin.  $(x^2 + y^2 = 1)$
>
> Point $B$ *lies inside* the unit circle centered at the origin.  $(x^2 + y^2 < 1)$
>
> Point $C$ *lies outside* the unit circle centered at the origin.  $(x^2 + y^2 > 1)$