# Is there a name for a point that lies on an ellipse?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections

I there a name for a point that falls on the perimeter of an ellipse?  In other words, if a polygon was a circle,  [what is the name of a point on the radius or a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102981/is-there-a-name-for-a-point-on-the-circumference-of-a-circle)?

Comment: It's just a point on the ellipse.  (Technically an ellipse only consists of the "boundary" of the ellipse and not the interior points.)

Comment: So in the link you've given, the answer is "a point on the circle".  By analogy, we'd expect the answer here to be "a point on the ellipse".  Do you think anything more special would happen with an ellipse?

Comment: @brian I expected there wasn't/isn't  an answer to my question but I didn't know for sure.

Comment: «A planet» ${}$